# What are the most used cooking ingredients?

Tags: stardew-valley

Stardew Valley allows players to cook dishes out of existing ingredients via a recipe. Some cooking ingredients are used in only one recipe, but some are required for multiple recipes.

**Of all the ingredients in Stardew Valley, what 5-10 ingredients are used in the *most* recipes, and what recipes are they used for?**

(I'd love a list of *all* ingredients with the number of recipes they're used in, but that's rather out of the scope of a question on this site.)

Reason (potential early-game spoiler):

> I'm hoping to make the best use of my upgraded house's fridge space. (I'd ask what the best ingredients to put in the fridge are, but that's opinion-based and therefore not appropriate for this site, either.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Unsurprisingly, the 5 most common ingredients in all of Stardew Valley's recipes are some of the most common ingredients in a real kitchen: flour, sugar, milk, oil, and eggs.

I took all ingredients listed on the [Cooking page of the Stardew wiki](https://stardewvalleywiki.com/Cooking#Recipes) and compiled them to find the ones used the most. Each ingredient is linked to a list of recipes it is used in.

- [Wheat Flour](https://stardewvalleywiki.com/Wheat_Flour#Recipes), 19 instances
- [Sugar](https://stardewvalleywiki.com/Sugar#Recipes), 16 instances
- [Milk](https://stardewvalleywiki.com/Milk#Recipes), 11 instances
- [Oil](https://stardewvalleywiki.com/Oil#Recipes), 10 instances
- [Egg](https://stardewvalleywiki.com/Egg#Recipes), 8 instances

Put together, these 5 ingredients are used in 40 of the 71 cooking recipes, not counting recipes that need a cooked dish using one of those base ingredients as an ingredient, such as the Farmer's Lunch having Omelet as an ingredient.

The next most used ingredient is [Tomato](https://stardewvalleywiki.com/Tomato#Recipes), with 6 different instances. After that, we fall to several ingredients used only in 3 or 4 recipes.

Comment: If you compiled this info for the entire list of recipes, would you mind posting the rest of it, as well?

Answer (score 3):

It took a little while, but I compiled a list of the most common items.

1. Wheat Flour (18)
2. Sugar (14)
3. Milk (10)
4. Oil (10)
5. Egg (7)
6. Tomato (6)
7. Vinegar (4)
8. Cranberries (4)
9. Cave Carrot (4)
10. Cheese (3)
11. Bread (3)
12. Mushroom (3)
13. Pumpkin (3)
14. Red Cabbage (3)

[I also made a post on reddit with a bit more detail.](https://www.reddit.com/r/StardewValley/comments/byr7pm/most_common_cooking_items/)